Exercise 10.10 of Humphrey's Lie algebra text
The problem is stated as follows:

Let $\Phi$ be a root system lying in the euclidean space $E$ and let $\Delta = \{\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_\ell\}$ be a basis for $\Phi$.  Let $\lambda = \sum_i k_i \alpha_i$ with all $k_i\geq 0$ or all $k_i\leq 0, k_i \in \mathbb Z.$ Prove that either $\lambda$ is a multiple (possibly 0) of a root, or else there exists $\sigma \in \mathscr W$ (Weyl group) such that $\sigma \lambda = \sum_{i=1}^l k_i'\alpha_i$ with some $k_i'>0$ and some $k_i'<0$.

Based on the sketch the author provided in the book, we first need to assume that $\lambda$ is not a multiple of any roots. Therefore $P_\lambda$ is not contained in $\bigcup_{\alpha \in \Phi} P_\alpha$, which means we can find a regular element $\mu \in P_\lambda \setminus \bigcup_{\alpha \in \Phi} P_\alpha$. Since $\mu$ is regular, we can find an element of the Weyl group $\sigma$ such that $(\alpha_i,\sigma(\mu))>0$ for all $\alpha_i \in \Delta$. Let
$$\sigma(\lambda) = k_i'\alpha_i$$
Then
\begin{align} 0 = (\lambda,\mu)= (\sigma \lambda, \sigma \mu)= \sum_{i=1}^l k_i'\cdot(\alpha_i,\sigma \mu)\end{align}
Here is where I get stuck, since as far as I understand, we also need to point out that $k'_i \ne 0$ for all $i$, but the identity $0 =\sum_{i=1}^l k_i'\cdot(\alpha_i,\sigma \mu)$ just say that there is both non-negative and non-positive coefficients $k_i'$, and there might be some $k_i'=0$.
Could anyone give me some hints? Thank you in advance.

The question does not require you to show that all the $k'_i$ are non-zero, only that the set $\{k'_i: 1\leq i\leq l\}$ contains both positive and negative integers.
If $\lambda$ is not a multiple of a root, then the hyperplane $P_\lambda$ orthogonal to it must contain regular elements, and if $\mu$ is such an element, there is an element of the Weyl group, $\sigma$ say, which takes it to the dominant chamber, that is, the subset of vectors $v$ which satisfy $(\alpha_i,v)>0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,\ell$. Then if $\sigma(\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^\ell k_i' \alpha_i$, the $k_i'$ must lie in $\mathbb Z$ becauses $W$ preserves the root lattice, and because $W$ acts by isometries we have the identity
$$
0 = (\lambda,\mu) = (\sigma(\lambda),\sigma(\mu)) = \sum_{I=1}^{\ell} k'_i(\alpha_i,\sigma(\mu))
$$
where all the inner products $(\alpha_i,\sigma(\mu))$ are strictly positive, by the choice of $\sigma$ and the regularity of $\mu$. Let $J = \{i: 1\leq i \leq \ell, k'_i<0\}$. Then we may rewrite the identity as
$$
\sum_{j \in J} (-k'_j)(\alpha_j,\sigma(\mu)) = \sum_{i \in J^c} k'_i(\alpha_i,\sigma(\mu))
$$
Now if $J$ is empty, then the left-hand side of this identity is $0$, while everything on the right-hand side is greater than or equal to zero, so can therefore equal zero only if all of the $k'_i$s are themselves $0$. But then $\sigma(\lambda)=0$, which is a contradiction. Thus $J$ cannot be empty. But then the left-hand side of the identity must be strictly positive, and hence so must the right-hand side, which implies that $J^c$ is nonempty also. Thus there are both positive and negative integers among the $k'_i$s.
On the other hand, if $t.\lambda \in \Phi$ for some $t>0$, then $\sigma(t.\lambda)=t.\sigma(\lambda)\in \Phi$ and hence if $t.\sigma(\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^k t.k'_i \alpha_i$ must have all $t.k'_i\geq 0$ or $t.k'_i\leq 0$ for all $i \in \{1,\ldots,l\}$, and since $t>0$ by assumption, it follows that the $k'_i$ are either all non-negative or all non-positive.

Thank you for the answer, but I am quite confused here: You said the identity implies the set of coefficients contains both negative and positive numbers, but how do we know that? I think it could be the case that $k_1'=0$, $k_2'>0$ and $k_3'<0$ etc.  When I read this question, I thought the author want to show that there is no coefficients that is zero. Sorry if I misunderstood something.

Ah, I think I see what you meant now. Do you mean the set $\left\lbrace k_i'\right\rbrace$ contains both non-negative and non-positive number?

@Tri I've updated my answer to hopefully make it clearer what happens when $\lambda$ is not a multiple of a root. Let me know if it helps!

Yes it helps a lot, I understood what you meant by now. Thank you.

Glad it clarified things!
